# Apache Stopped Following Symlinks

Tags: apache, symlink

Yesterday, I had a fistful of sites running locally with no problem. Today, nothing opens and I have a log full of this:

```
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www
```

I have no idea what I did (I didn't open/change my httpd.conf file in any way), but clearly it was something bad. I run virtual hosts and the root directories are located in `~/Developer/www`. In order to share the config files across multiple Macs with different home directories, I've created a symlink, `/var/www` which points to `~/Developer/www`.

All of the virtualhost config files point their `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/project_directory` and its own root directory has the `FollowSymLinks` option:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName   localhost
  ServerAlias  localhost.local localhost.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/_localhost

  <Directory /var/www/_localhost>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My main `httpd.conf` file, similarly, has the `FollowSymLinks` option enabled for `/`:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Any idea what I could have done to stop Apache from understanding symlinks or, better yet, what I can do to get it back on track?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I should add that all of the directories in the "stack" are executable by all users and that this is the native Apache install on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I made an assumption that I shouldn't have. I had verified every relevant permission *except* the one that evidently mattered. Apache didn't have execute permissions on my top level home directory. I checked, re-checked and triple checked everything under that, but having never changed anything in that directory itself, I just didn't anticipate it being the issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The symlink was created with the root user, not the virtual host user.. So apache couldn't see the symlinks.. changing the owner of the symlink worked like a charm